# Is it possible to get country name of the developers in Github?

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

I need to query the developer num from different countries for research, but I can not get the country name of the developers, like this:

```
"location": "xxx, China"
```

Where can I get all the country name in Github?

As suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen, I make GET request to the Github:

```
var theUrl = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:china";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send( null );
var reponseJson = xmlHttp.responseText;
obj = JSON.parse(reponseJson);
// Print obj
```

Comment: Can you show us the full query you are currently trying?

Comment: Ok, thx for suggestion.

Comment: Is your question regarding that you don't see the `location` as a field in the result, or that your query isn't working?  I believe your query should return all users located in China.

Answer (score 1):

According to GitHub API, `/users` returns a response different than a single `/user` request.
This is probably done in order to save bandwidth, but also under the view that location information and other attributes may no be necessary in pages displaying multiple values.

Available attributes in `/users` requests according to the documentation are:

```
{
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1,
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
    "following_url":     "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
}
```

If you need location data for several users but a small amount, it seems like best method would be to query `/users` page by page, and map to full user data by requesting each user separately.

Sources:

- [GitHub Users API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users)

Comment: Yeah. I noticed that, I can not get accurate developer num just according to location. Any other way to get accurate num?

Comment: It seems like this is not available via public API. If your research might be of interest for GitHub, I suggest contacting them, as they most probably have session data which can be analysed and provide a more accurate picture.

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I get all the country name in Github?

From [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users):

> [`location`](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-users#search-based-on-the-location-where-a-user-resides) Filter users by the location indicated in their profile.

The location field in GitHub user profiles is optional, and freeform. I could set mine to say "China" right now, even though I live in Canada. Or set it to "", or "Betelgeuse", for that matter.

Depending on the kind of research you are doing you might not want to rely on the location data provided by GitHub.

GitHub does not provide a country field.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. I can not get accurate developer num just according to the location. Any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @triffic, the problem you're trying to solve isn't entirely clear to me. It looks like "I want to know the number of developers who use GitHub, broken down by country". If that's your question, I'm not sure what other options you have. GitHub's web server logs will have more reliable data, but that's not perfect either (e.g. I could use a VPN located in another country), and I strongly doubt that they'll share them with you.

Comment: Yeah, "I want to know the number of developers who use GitHub, broken down by country", That's exactly what I want.